# annotations made with evince appear in preview, but not in physical print-out

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, osx-el-capitan, evince, preview.app

I made annotations with evince to a PDF and saved the PDF. I invested many hours of work into this so the annotations (colored highlighting) is valuable to me.

Now I must print the PDF from an OS X system. I open the PDF with preview and I can see my highlights fine. But when I print the document, the annotations (highlights) are not in the actual print out.

Target machine is a color laser printer.

I never had any problems with printing so far in this setup.

Can I somehow print my evince-annotated PDF under OS X, such that the annotations appear in the print-out? If yes, how?

Versions used:

Ubuntu side:

- "Document Viewer" 3.18.12 (evince)
- Xubuntu 16.04 LTS

OS X side:

- El Capitan 10.11.15
- preview.app Version 8.1 (877.7)

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around for Ubuntu:

1. Install Xournal on Ubuntu

   ```
   sudo apt install xournal
   ```
2. Open the pdf in Xournal
3. Select `File` -> `Export to PDF`

It still wasn't perfect to me: Highlights made some texts invisible. But by playing with the Annotation-properties in evince (before step 2) I managed to see the text as well.

Comment: I didn't try Xournal, but printing to PDF in Xournal++ makes annotations disappear. (Annotations were created with Evince.)

Answer (score 0):

Does selecting `Show notes` checkbox in Preview's print dialogue help?

[image: Checked Show notes checkbox]

Discussion:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4276999?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: It does not! Even with "Show notes" checked, highlight annotations still show up on screen in preview, but are not to be seen in print!